# stage.rviz missing and URDF

Tags: simulation, rviz, urdf, stage, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I followed the tutorial on stage for simulating one robot but in the stage stack there is not such file as a stage.rviz. Only a stage.vcg which according to the error prompted is the old extension file.
Where can I find the stage.rviz I can't see to find it anywhere.

Second, I have a URDF file for my robot. How can I load it in Stage using Rviz ? I know that Rviz is going to use it if I launch joint_state_publisher and launch the robot_state_publisher node with my URDF in argument. But will it works if I use that command ?

```
roscd stage
rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find stage_ros`/rviz/stage.rviz
```

I would try it myself but I just can't find a stage.rviz to load and try for now. I just don't really quite see how to combine everything here. What I want to achieve is to use a stage world for the simulation in Rviz as I want to design a path finding robot. I just want to give him some sort of "world to play with".

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138471/stage.rviz-missing-and-urdf/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jackel Fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/18491/jackel-fox/) on 2014-06-22**:
Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll just half answer myself in case someone is wondering. Just load the URDF in the parameter and it should be working, the robot model will be loaded. I still don't know where to find stage.rviz.

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-13**:
I suspect the stage maintainers haven't upgraded the rviz configuration, and stage.rviz simply doesn't exist.